# Group theory notation used in physics (AdS/CFT)

Tags: group-theory, ads-cft, notation

This in the context of the AdS/CFT correspondence. I am reading [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep--th/9905111.pdf) review on AdS/CFT Aharony et. al. (The MAGOO review)  The abstract can be found [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111)

Equation (2.50) of the above paper lists the $R$-symmetry groups of extended supersymmetries in $AdS_{p+2}$. He uses the following notation for the group:

> $AdS_5: SU(2,2 | {\cal N}/2),~{\cal N}=2,4,6,8$

Can anyone explain this notation to me?

Comment: http://www.slac.stanford.edu/econf/C0906083/pdf/10.pdf

Comment: Beisert has a nice chapter on this http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.4004 which is part of the huge AdS/CFT-integrability review.